# No matching distribution found for pywin32>=223 (from pypiwin32->-r /tmp/app/requirements.txt

Tags: python, flask-restful, cloud-foundry, pyenchant

I am using `Python 3.6` and trying to deploy web service on `pivotal cloud foundry`.

First of all I was getting an error for `pyenchant`, then I came to know that I have to use/install `pypiwin32`.

I have not used `pywin32` anywhere, I have mentioned `pypiwin32` in requirements.txt.

When I run `cf push` command to deploy app, it gives me error.

> Could not find a version that satisfies the requirement pywin32>=223
>   (from pypiwin32->-r /tmp/app/requirements.txt (line 230)) (from
>   versions: )
>             No matching distribution found for pywin32>=223 (from pypiwin32->-r /tmp/app/requirements.txt (line 230))
>             You are using pip version 18.1, however version 20.0.2 is available.
>             You should consider upgrading via the 'pip install --upgrade pip' command.
>             **ERROR** Could not install pip packages: could not run pip: exit status 1    Failed to compile droplet: Failed to run all supply
>   scripts: exit status 14    Exit status 223

On local machine, `pypiwin32` , `pywin32` and `pyenchant` got successfully installed but not able to understand why above error is coming while deploying an app.

Comment: Are you running locally on Windows? It looks like these are Windows related libraries and when you push to Pivotal Cloud Foundry, your Python app will be running on Linux. What error do you get if you remove that from requirements.txt?

Comment: I am running on Windows 10, it does not work without requirements.txt

Comment: It is not possible to run Python apps on the Windows stack. The Python buildpack for Cloud Foundry *only* works on the Linux based stack. If it is a hard requirement to have Windows, you won't be able to run your app on Cloud Foundry, at least not using the Python buildpack based deployment.